# Cisco Router config help? (probably OSPF related)

Tags: cisco

http://pastebin.com/909gfRRL

I'm assuming something is messed up with router As's ospf because I can ping everything except pc-A. Only one PC connected to each router. I'm stuck though, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you add any more detail to your question. Things like, where are you pinging from (IP), what happens when you try? The output of the routing table on the affected devices etc etc

Comment: Where is PC A connected, which interface on Router A and what is its IP and subnet mask?

Comment: Please don't deface or obliterate your questions; if you want the question deleted, please raise a flag for a moderator to delete it

Answer (score 1):

It would help with a topology to better understand your setup and to see routing tables and if all the routers respond to ping from every other router. One of the problems seems to be that Serial0/1/1 is shutdown on Router B which I assume is the interface that connects to Router A. Also you have different subnet masks on the two interfaces which you should not have. Serial0/1/1 on Router B has a /25 and Serial0/0/0 on Router A has a /30.

Router B advertize the network 4.0.0.0 /8 but I can't see that it has any interface connected to it which seems unnecessary.

It might also help to advertize the link networks connecting Router C and D and Router C and B into OSPF to make sure that Router A knows how to get to the other routers.